# compare two files and save the difference in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I like to compare two text files and save the difference under linux.

I know there are tools like kdiff, diff vimdiff etc. but my expectation are as follows.

1. Output should be in a separate file
2. The difference should be quoted with colours, ex: delete line in red and added line in green something like that
3. It should ignore space differences
4. It should be an opensource tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `tkdiff4 -w file-name1 file-name2`

It fulfills all your requirements. Specific color might be an issue.

Comment: how to open the saved output? I meant which application?

Comment: @Thangaraj "how to open the saved output?" -- You don't know how to open a file? "I meant which application?" -- You need to express yourself more clearly.

Comment: @JimBalter When I did a tkdiff, it showed me the difference in two windows and generated the report. but when I open it, opened in gedit, which is default application. In that I could see only the text not the difference. Thats why I just asked :)

Comment: @Thangaraj The answer refers to `tkdiff4`, which I take to be something different from `tkdiff`, which is a graphical tool that doesn't take a `-b` argument. If the answer doesn't work for you, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

try `colordiff` and `man diff` for options for ignoring whitespace etc

Answer (score 0):

Like,

```
#!/bin/bash
wdiff -w "\e[31m" -x "\e[0m" -y "\e[32m" -z "\e[0m" "$@";
```

replace \e by, well, the ASCII character with value 0x1A. Put the two commands into some file, and run it using redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Save the changes to a file:

```
diff -Nur originalfile newfile > patchfile
```

Use the difference file to change the origin file:

```
patch originfile patchfile
```

I think this is the easiest way to save the changes and reload the changes.
By the way, you can use this command the create an update-package.